# If you can't add ASP includes in SharepPoint 2010... Then what?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm having an extremely difficult time trying figure how to implemented some type of way to use ASP includes in SharePoint 2010. If you can't please please please help me with another way of doing so.

I found a solution, but I'm not completely happy with..

============HTML============

```
        <div class="js-include" title="test.html"></div>
```

============JQUERY============

```
$(function () {
//Trigger global pages
$(".js-include").each(function(){
    var inc=$(this);
    $.get(inc.attr("title"), function(data){
        inc.replaceWith(data);
    });
});});
```

Comment: What are you trying to include? Server Side content can be added by web parts, user controls, even code-behind if you really want.

Comment: You can ask SharePoint related questions in StackExchange's dedicated SharePoint site, [here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm trying to include a custom header and footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [The Case of Server Side Includes in Sharepoint Continued](http://sharepointallthetime.blogspot.com/2009/06/case-of-server-side-includes-in.html) for an example of how to use the XML Web Part to duplicate in SharePoint what the `<!-- #include file -->` directive accomplishes in ASP.

However, as @PaulLeigh said, since SharePoint is built upon ASP.NET, I would highly recommend embracing Master Pages and user controls as replacements for ASP styled server side includes.

Comment: I would recommend http://www.asp.net. They have great resources. From a quick search, you might want to check out [Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages) and [Create a Custom User Control in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-user-control-in-aspnet).